# error CS1736: Default parameter value for 'bulletSpeed' must be a compile-time constant

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a game with Unity 2D. The following code throws an error "error CS1736: Default parameter value for 'bulletSpeed' must be a compile-time constant" which, quite frankly, I can't figure out how to fix.
Here's the guilty code:

```
 private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private MovementController checkForSlowMotion;
    private float bulletSpeednew;
    //private float bulletSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        checkForSlowMotion = GameObject.Find("Player").GetComponent<MovementController>();
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public void MoveBullet(float bulletSpeed = bulletSpeednew)
    {
        if (checkForSlowMotion.slowDown == true)
        {
            this.bulletSpeed = 1.0f;
        }
        else if (checkForSlowMotion.slowDown == false)
        {
            bulletSpeed = 10.0f;
        }
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + transform.right * bulletSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

I have tried passing a non-static variable "bulletspeednew" as "bulletSpeed", unsuccessfully.

Comment: you can't use variables as default values, change `public void MoveBullet(float bulletSpeed = bulletSpeednew)` to something like `public void MoveBullet(float bulletSpeed = 5f)`

Comment: The documentation for CS1736 with examples and solutions (as well as all other CSNNNN errors) is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs1736

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

As Ron mentioned in his comment, C# doesn't allow none-const variables (IE variables whose value can change during runtime, like serialized fields in Unity) to be used as default values in function signatures, I think your best bet here would be to set the "default" value with an [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/member-overloading).

```
public void MoveBullet()
{
    MoveBullet (bulletSpeednew);
}

public void MoveBullet(float bulletSpeed)
{
    //...
}
```